# How to use groupBy data based on the server and display it in ag-grid - angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to group the data based on the server name which is the object key `server`?

here's the code:

```
    rowData = [
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 1",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 2",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        },
        {
          server: "Server 2",
          ping: "10 ms",
          dl: "50Mbit/s",
          ul: "50Mbit/s",
          ispcon: true,
          dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
          datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
        }
      ];
```

output should be like this.

```
[
{
 server: "Server 1",
 data: [
  {
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  },{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
  }
 ]
 },
{
 server: "Server 2",
 data: [
{
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
    },
    {
      ping: "10 ms",
      dl: "50Mbit/s",
      ul: "50Mbit/s",
      ispcon: true,
      dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
      datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
    }
]
}
]
```

What I want is to group the data based on the server, example when the data and it server is "Server 1" it should group the data who has a server "Server 1".

and how to display it in ag-grid (master detail).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-xabqct?file=src/app/app.component.ts

output should be like this.
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: this have a simple js vanilla solution, why u ask for angular?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo for displaying data in ag-grid

Comment: Are you happy to use a library like lodash, or do you need the grouping algorithm? Lodash makes this kind of collection manipulation a cinch, and makes the code readable and clean.

Comment: @seesharper using the lodash groupBy?

Comment: @seesharper yes.

Comment: Yes, exactly: `_.groupBy(rowData, d => d.server)`. Can't get easier than that!

Comment: (sorry - put the wrong code. fixed)

Comment: can you create a sample in stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```js
const rowData = [
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 1",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 2",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
},
{
  server: "Server 2",
  ping: "10 ms",
  dl: "50Mbit/s",
  ul: "50Mbit/s",
  ispcon: true,
  dateStart: "2019-10-12 09:00:00",
  datteEnd: "2019-10-12 09:05:000"
}
];

  
const result = rowData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (acc.findIndex(a => a.server === item.server) === -1) {
    acc.push({server: item.server, data: []})
  }
  const currentIndex = acc.findIndex(a => a.server === item.server)

  delete item['server']
  acc[currentIndex].data.push(item)

  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```